# When a click on a link,the target page is just showed up when fully loaded

Tags: php, jquery, hyperlink, loading

I have 2 php pages: A and B. Page A has a link for B.

Page B has lot of functions (including jquery functions) and takes about 10 sec to fully load.

The issue is:

When i click on page's A link, page B is just showed up when it's fully loaded. In this mean time page A keeps 'thinking'.

My intention is when I click on page's A link it instantly goes to page B, and on page B I use a javascript to show a "loading" gif animation until page it's not fully loaded.

Strange because it works properly on my localhost, but not on the server(linux). Maybe something on php.ini? (i've tried output_buffer=off, but it didn't work). Any suggestions?

thanks!!!

Comment: You should probably post some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there's buffering going on on the server. Try calling ob_flush(), flush(), ob_flush(), flush(). Sometimes you need to call them multiple times, so I call them like that.

ob_flush() will flush any output buffer you have. flush() will flush any apache buffer, although some modules may still cause it to buffer.

It sounds like this is an environmental issue, not a code issue, so if you're still having errors I'd look and see what's different between the environments.

Comment: Regarding the ob_flush it should be used on the target page first line?  And the difference on environment is just on php.ini or there's another kind of settings?thank you

Comment: Do it after your first input, like the header portion if you can. The environment issue could be anything from php.ini to httpd.conf (assuming you're using apache) to a load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

just found out

Just got in contact with my server help desk...My server does not allow output_buffer to be Off.even if it's set on php.ini.So no solutions

thanks all